# Docker tutorial not working for springboot+mysql+react application

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, docker, docker-toolbox

I am trying to familiarize myself with docker and applications with spring-boot, mysql and react and I want to run this example: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-mysql-react-docker-compose-example/ ( the github repo of the source is :https://github.com/callicoder/spring-security-react-ant-design-polls-app. 
I have changed the database_user and password accordingly to mysql( user: root password: no password ->blank field)

I use docker-compose up -d to start it. I get no errors, the containers are made and existing images but in browser I get a : this site can't be reached when trying: localhost:3000 or 3001 or 127.0.0.1:3000 or localhost:9090 .

I can see in docker that the containers are running and their ports :https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3bmg.jpg

Those ports don't work also. I try with my machine's  virtual box addresses, they don't work.

I have win10 HOME and  I use docker-toolbox(not docker desktop) installed using  https://medium.com/@mbyfieldcameron/docker-on-windows-10-home-edition-c186c538dff3
 Edit: 
Using docker logs (server_containerID) I have found a possible issue in the server application:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.192.3' (using password: NO)
```

However, the mysql container runs alright( I run it with :  docker run -e  MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 mysql:8) and it shows that it can connect/ awaits connection with the server.
Any idea on how I could access the application? Thank you!

Figured out, apparently the address is 192.168.99.100:9090.

Comment: I suggest to launch docker-compose without `-d` flag so that you will see those containers logs and troubleshoot what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned that repository and ran

```
docker-compose up -d
```

in my machine with running docker containers,

[image]

Docker container for `react-app` is running in `9090` port, you should hit http://localhost:9090 (*NOT* localhost:3000, etc) in the browser.

As you have changed MySQL credential - changes should be made in `docker-compose.yml` file and `application.properties` file from `spring-boot` project.

Here is the result,

[image]

If you're still facing the issue, try to see the logs of `spring-security-react-ant-design-polls-app_app-server_1` by executing,

```
docker logs -f spring-security-react-ant-design-polls-app_app-server_1
```

Seeing the server-log - you may encounter the issue.

Comment: I have changed the docker-compose.yml and the application.properties file to fit my mysql server.  But I still can not access it, even from  http://localhost:9090( I have tried that as well)

Comment: Did you see the logs as well? and what about `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` and `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD` properties in docker-compose file?

Comment: Please see the logs executing `docker logs -f spring-security-react-ant-design-polls-app_app-server_1` command

Comment: Here is the modifications I did for mysql to the project https://github.com/Diana-Ioana/Docker

Comment: @DianaG it seems `mysql:8` is giving the issue - you may overcome it by changing with `mysql:5.7`

Comment: Figured out the issue. The address was 192.168.99.100:9090.  Apparently, docker toolbox replaced localhost with 192.168.99.100.